# JWT.io is verifying the token based on empty secret and saying signature is verified

Tags: security, jwt, json-web-signature, jwt.io

I am totally new to this, so please bear with my question if it's utterly stupid.  I am learning how to verify signature using https://jwt.io

The following is what I am doing

### Generated Public/Private Key Pair

Private Key

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,4A6A48288A531DCA

m2glcvku6rdV8z0QBsBc3Hc72vG4NN3wIPnqdC47FTA3y9WiD7Ukh4m3ZpL2mraz
7PSblIe8ob/aaG9TYViIb4QRYZFg8z3jR6WeNEhC2EbC2CwkSSH3ug8ViQ+1i8d1
kMnQDK1i/s0BZvxlhKPuSy2kOIjelWctkDHvJyvU/WQ=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Public Key

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBHpqkegB/A/12vqfApHOaFXaJcHkyhNw1u9XnZe2+hiDT698U4c3iet5VyTo3D1DOe7Xi5dG07UorsMvWCmSbvU=
```

I used [this](https://8gwifi.org/sshfunctions.jsp) website to generate **ECDSA-256** pair of keys with passphrase as **H2**

### Create a JSON Web Token (JWT)

I used http://jwtbuilder.jamiekurtz.com/ to generate the token

I used the private key to sign the `JWT`.  The following is the token

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJIYXJpdCIsImlhdCI6MTU4Nzc1MjM3NCwiZXhwIjoxNjE5Mjg4Mzc0LCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5oYXJpdC5kZXYiLCJzdWIiOiJjb250YWN0QGhhcml0LmNvbSIsIkdpdmVuTmFtZSI6Ikhhcml0IiwiU3VybmFtZSI6IkhpbWFuc2h1In0.pmvGfBXH4603YMGYDB6qOXlQjhfdPulvbODrK70ihS0
```

### Verify

I go to the website https://jwt.io and below is the video of what I tried

[image: JWT Issue]

## Question

How JWT is verifying and telling it as a valid signature when the secret is empty. I have not even provided the secret yet.

What am I missing?

Comment: btw., you write a lot about the public and private key you generated, but then you ended up generating a token with HS256 algorithm (symmetric key), so you're not really using your assymetric key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you paste a token on the left side and then change the secret or key in the input field in the right column, a new signature is calculated and then automatically verified. And the secret can also be empty, not advisable but possible.

Please observe what happens to the signature part of your token in the left column. You'll notice that it changed!

This often leads to misunderstandings, people asked here why their token was verified with a given secret, but their API said it's invalid. But they didn't notice that the signature was recalculated when they entered the secret.

If you want to check if the token can be verified with a given secret, you always need to **first** paste the secret into the input field in the right column (under VERIFY SIGNATURE) and **then** paste the token to the left column.

Comment: Does that mean as long as I know the secret I can fake anyone's JWT?

Comment: Yes, if you know the secret, you can create a valid token. But a secret should be handled as such and not be known by anyone.